# Spring property file loader: how to update properties at runtime, whenever they are updated in file?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, properties

I am using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to load the property file using spring.

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
       <property name="locations">
          <list>        
             <value>file:${applicationProperties}</value>    
          </list>
       </property>
    </bean>
```

I have override this PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to store all the key value pair in a Map. Now the requirement is whenever this property file is updated and saved on the file system, then this map should get updated with new values at run-time.

How to achieve this requirement?

Comment: somebody has extended it to support this https://github.com/Unicon/springframework-addons/wiki/Auto-reloading-properties-files

Answer (score -2):

You have to use beanfactory postprocessor:

**Application-context.xml**

```xml
<bean id="connection" class="com.bfpp.beans.Connectionmanager">
<property name="url" value="${db.url}"></property>
<property name="username" value="${db.un}"></property>
<property name="pass" value="${db.pwd}"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="pphc" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location" value="classpath:db.properties"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

write respective connection bean 
**In test class**

```java
        ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/bfpp/common/application-context.xml");
        /*BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("com/bfpp/common/application-context.xml"));*/
        /*BeanFactoryPostProcessor bfpp=factory.getBean("pphc",BeanFactoryPostProcessor.class);
        bfpp.postProcessBeanFactory((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) factory);*/
        Connectionmanager c=ctx.getBean("connection",Connectionmanager.class);
        System.out.println(c);
```

**write db.properties**

```
db.url=jdbc:odbc:thin@1521:xe
db.un=username
db.pwd=password
```

These will be replaced in xml file before bean initializing takes place.
In case of `beanfactory` beans will be loaded when we call `getBean()` method so code in comments is not required if we use applicationcontext as it creates beans at time of creating `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` itself.